# Grails 3 - index string so ilike("propertyName", "%value%") is faster

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

How can I index a String property of a domain object so that queries such as `ilike("propertyName", "%value%")` run faster?

Answer (score 0):

The ORM DSL within Grails 3 allows you to specify which columns are used in which indexes. The **8.2.6. Database Indices** section of the [ORM DSL documentation](http://gorm.grails.org/6.0.x/hibernate/manual/index.html#ormdsl) explains it with the following example:

```
class Person {
    String firstName
    String address
    static mapping = {
        table 'people'
        version false
        id column: 'person_id'
        firstName column: 'First_Name', index: 'Name_Idx'
        address column: 'Address', index: 'Name_Idx,Address_Index'
    }
}
```

In the above example the `firstName` property uses an index called `Name_Idx`. Note that the `address` property uses multiple indexes and there is **no space** between them.

As far as if this will improve performance of your `ilike` query, that depends on a great number of factors (not the least of which is the data you are searching).